# Help with compact notation for sum

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I've already understood the motive of this sum using the nom-compact way, but I want to do it in the compact way, so it will be rigorous. Please, I need some help:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+\frac{n}{2n+1} = $$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$$

Well, I'm not lazy, I really understood what's happening, I've tried changing the index of some sums but I couldn't do it. I want to proof it without expanding the sum, only by doing manipulations with the compact notation for sums.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking whether the stated equalities are true?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, I imagine the OP wrote out some terms of each sum, saw the pattern, and drew conclusions, but now wants help constructing a more rigorous proof.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese this is given to me as true. I want to be able to verify it, just by starting from the first line: $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+\frac{n}{2n+1}$. If I know how to arrive at the second line, then it will already help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the four terms, the first two look most similar. The only difference between the two is the fact that one has denominator $2k - 1$ whilst the other has denominator $2k+1$. It would be nice if we could combine these two terms. We're going to convert the denominator $2k+1$ to $2k-1$, but we could go the other way. Note that $2k + 1 = 2(k+1) - 1$ so we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2(k+1)-1} = \sum_{l=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2l-1}$$

where the last equality occurs due to a change of index, $l := k + 1$. As the name of the index is irrelevant, you can replace $l$ by $k$. Doing so gives

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2k-1} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$

where we have split off the first term of the first summation and the last term of the second summation so that now the index in both summations runs over the same values. Simplifying we obtain

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} + \frac{n+1}{2n+1}.$$

If we want the summation to start at $k = 1$ instead of $k=2$ we can do that by realising that the term in the sum corresponding to $k = 1$ would be $1$ so we begin the summation at $k = 1$ and then subtract $1$ so that we don't change the expression. So we obtain

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} + \frac{n+1}{2n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} - 1 + \frac{n+1}{2n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{n}{2n+1}.$$

Now we have combined the first two terms. In terms of the initial expression we have

\begin{align*}
& \left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+\frac{n}{2n+1}\\
=& \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{n}{2n+1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+\frac{n}{2n+1}\\
=& \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}
\end{align*}

which is the second expression you provided in your post. Note that we can rewrite this slightly as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}.$$

Now we see that the terms in the first summation are reciprocals of odd numbers between $1$ and $2n-1$, and the terms in the second summation are reciprocals of even numbers between $2$ and $2n$. If we had the sum of these two summations, we could combine it into a single summation which had terms which where the reciprocals of positive integers between $1$ and $2n$. That is,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}.$$

Unfortunately, we do not have the sum of these two summations, but rather their difference. However, we can use this equality to help simplify our expression. Note that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k} - 2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}.
\end{align*}

So the initial expression reduces to the right hand side of the last equality. But now we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$

which is the third expression you provided in your post. Now the terms in the first summation are reciprocals of positive integers between $1$ and $2n$, while the terms in the second summation are reciprocals of positive integers between $1$ and $n$. The only terms which remain once the subtraction is performed are the reciprocals of the positive integers betweeen $n+1$ and $2n$. So we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{l=1}^n\frac{1}{n+l}$$

where the last equality occurs due to a change of index, $l := k-n$. Finally, as the name of the index is irrelevant, you can replace $l$ by $k$. Doing so gives

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$$

which is the final expression you provided in your post.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see the pattern, write out a few terms
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1} = 1/1 + 1/3+ 1/5 + 1/7 \cdots
$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+1} =1/3+ 1/5 + 1/7 \cdots
$$
So these two can be combined except the extra term in the first sum.

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} =1/1+ 1/2 + 1/3 +1/4+1/5\cdots
$$

Again you can see common terms with the others. With *practice* you will start to notice these patterns. There is no magic formula, just practice.

Comment: I really saw the pattern. I expanded the terms and recognized this as true. But what I wanted to do, is to be more rigorous, by proving it just manipulating the compact notation, without expanding.